# Why does this function print 0 when I pass in a nonzero value as its argument?

Tags: c, function, function-prototypes

The code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    test(7.4, 4);
    return 0;
}

void test(float height, float radius){
    printf("%f", height);    
}
```

Will print:

```
0.000000
```

Why is this? Why will it not just print 7.4?

Comment: What happens when you put the `test()` definition _above_ main? What happens when you suffix `7.4` with an `f` (e.g. `7.4f`)? As is, your code shouldn't compile under a standards compliant compiler - and if it is, my shot-in-the-dark guess is that the prototype is being implicitly created since it's not above main and causing some weird issues. I'm also not sure this is _really_ your code since it looks hacked up and won't compile. Would you please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Did you look at the compiler warnings?

Comment: Everything **Qix** said. The gcc version [ideone](https://ideone.com/emKQI6) uses prints `-0.00000`.

Comment: @qix wow, putting `test()` above `main()` totally fixed it. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @Alfie, **templatetypedef** gives a thorough explanation

Comment: FWIW this is a great example of implicit declarations. Good find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the program you wrote, you've called the `test` function without first prototyping it. Modern compilers will often reject this, but on older compilers - or compilers providing support for old C code - the program will implicitly try to deduce the argument types. You've provided `7.4` and `4` as arguments, meaning that the compiler expects that you're going to be passing in a `double` and an `int`, respectively, since `7.4` is a `double` literal, so it generates code to pass in the first argument as a `double` and the second as an `int`.

Later, when you actually define `test`, you specify that the arguments are `float`s, which doesn't match the earlier code. As a result, that function tries to read its first argument as though it were a `float`, so it ends up reinterpreting some of the bytes in some way that happens to interpret them as a floating point number that's close to negative zero.

To fix this, either prototype the `test` function before calling it, or define it before you use it. Note that my compiler with the warnings cranked up explicitly tells you about the implicit declaration and the definition mismatch:

```
nodecl.c: In function ‘main’:
nodecl.c:4:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘test’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   test(7.4, 4);
   ^
nodecl.c: At top level:
nodecl.c:8:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘test’
 void test(float height, float radius){
      ^
nodecl.c:4:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘test’ was here
   test(7.4, 4);
   ^
```

Going forward, if you see these warnings, you now know what they're talking about, and you should be able to diagnose your error more quickly.

Comment: If `7.4` (represented in IEEE754 double-precision format) is misinterpreted as two adjacent single-precision values, those are `-1.5881868392106856e-23` and `2.4624998569488525`.  The first of those rounds to `-0.000000` when printed in `%f` format.

Comment: Check out @MarcoGuerri's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39906531/510036) for a bytecode explanation for those whom are so inclined.

Answer (score 2):

Under Linux with gcc this is what happens: the compiler is passing `7.4` as double, due to the fact that `test` prototype is defined only after main.

```
0000000000400506 <main>:
  400506:       55                      push   %rbp
  400507:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40050a:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  40050e:       48 b8 9a 99 99 99 99    movabs $0x401d99999999999a,%rax
  400515:       99 1d 40 
  400518:       bf 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%edi
  40051d:       48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  400521:       f2 0f 10 45 f8          movsd  -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
  400526:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  40052b:       e8 07 00 00 00          callq  400537 <test>
  400530:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400535:       c9                      leaveq 
  400536:       c3                      retq
```

That `0x401d99999999999a` is your 64 bits double, i.e. 7.4. The `test` function is interpreting that value as a single precision number (float, as specified in the prototype), passing it to `printf` using `cvtss2sd` (float to double conversion) via `xmm0`:

```
0000000000400537 <test>:
  400537:       55                      push   %rbp
  400538:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40053b:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  40053f:       f3 0f 11 45 fc          movss  %xmm0,-0x4(%rbp)
  400544:       f3 0f 11 4d f8          movss  %xmm1,-0x8(%rbp)
  400549:       f3 0f 5a 45 fc          cvtss2sd -0x4(%rbp),%xmm0
  40054e:       bf e4 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005e4,%edi
  400553:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  400558:       e8 83 fe ff ff          callq  4003e0 <printf@plt>
  40055d:       c9                      leaveq 
  40055e:       c3                      retq   
  40055f:       90                      nop
```

This causes only a fraction of your initial 64 bits value to be converted to the actual double printed to stdout, i.e. 0x9999999a, yeilding that close to 0 result.

Answer (score 1):

Turn compiler warning up - and fix what it warns against.
Use a function prototype for `test()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled your program in GGC compiler, I got the following error

```
 float.c:11:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘test’ [enabled by default]
 void test(float height, float radius)
      ^
float.c:7:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘test’ was here
     test(7.4, 4);
     ^
```

Then I added prototype of `test()` function befor main() function like

```
void test(float, float);
```

Then Compiled again, I got correct output.So, add prototype of `test()` function.